# Probability that total number of sixes in $n$ dice tosses

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, dice

> Let X be the total count of fives in $n$ dice ups and downs s.t. it is in between  $\frac 1 k n +/- \sqrt n$  with k=6. Calculate Pr(X).

I personally think that I  should integrate the probability density function of n such that it is in between the two values? I dont know how to find that pdf but I know for n throws, you expect to get n/6 sixes. any hin would be helpful thanks!

Comment: This probability goes to zero. Are you sure about the exercise?

Comment: so sorry i had a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p= \frac{1}{6}$, $q=1-p$, $\mu = \frac{n}{6}$, $\sigma = \sqrt{npq}$. With Chebychev:

$$P(|X-\mu|\lt \sqrt{n}) \geq 1- \frac{\sigma^2}{n}= 1- \frac{npq}{n} = 1- \frac{5}{36}=\frac{31}{36}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Let $Y \sim Bin(n, \frac16)$
- Use Chebyshev's inequality on $Pr \left(|Y-\mathbb{E}(Y)|\ge \sqrt{n} \right)$

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem which can be solved using the [concentration inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality) approach. Specifically, you use (a variant of) [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) to obtain $$\mathbb{P}(X-n/6>x)\le \inf_{\theta>0}e^{-\theta x}\mathbb{E}(e^{\theta (X-n/6)}),$$ which is called the [Chernoff's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) in literature. Now, noting that $X=\sum_{k=0}^n I(X_k=1)$, where $X_k$ is the random variable which is $1$ is we get a $6$ in the $k$ th trial, and $0$ otherwise, so that $\mathbb{E}X_k = 1/6$. Furthermore, $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ are all i.i.d. Then, $$\mathbb{E}(e^{\theta(X-n/6)})=\prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}(e^{\theta(X_k-1/6)})=\left(1/6e^{5\theta/6}+5/6e^{-\theta/6}\right)^n$$ It is now a matter of minimizing the function $e^{-\theta x}\left(1/6e^{5\theta/6}+5/6e^{-\theta/6}\right)^n$ over all $\theta >0$. We can easily find that the minimum is obtained at the solution of $$-x + 5n\frac{e^{5\theta/6}-e^{-\theta/6}}{e^{5\theta/6}+5e^{-\theta/6}}=0\implies \theta = \ln \left(\frac{n+x}{n-x/5}\right)$$ Substituting this value of $\theta$ in the original expression finds a bound on the probability, from which the desired result can be obtained, maybe after a few manipulations.

Comment: is this a little overcopmlicating everything though? it seems much more complicated than chebychev?

Comment: I agree. At the outset, this approach might seem a little too much, but if you need to have a very tight bound on the probability, this is the standard approach to take. Often Chebyshev works well too, but I just thought that this approach is worth mentioning if you are willing to find a very tight upper bound.

Comment: so this actualy gives a better result than the chebychev?

Comment: Where you can explicitly find the bound in chernoff's bound, there it is better than Chebyshev.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** $P(a< X\leq b) = P(X\leq b) - P(x\leq a) = F_X(b) - F_X(a)$

Comment: Your "Hint" is true and irrelevant. Please explain.